# Gon variable is not defined in js.erb file using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, highcharts

I have a highchart that is being rendered by a `js.erb` file in conjunction with the `gon` variable. The setup that I have is that a user will load a page and once the page is ready an ajax call will be made to a separate controller. The controller will handle the data needed, assign it to gon and will render the appropriate `js.erb` file with the data. However, I keep observing that `gon` is consistently undefined and the variables are not being sent to `gon`. I wonder if this has to do with ajax but here is my code and logic flow.

Here is where the call originates

```
_vulnerabilites_per_version.html.haml

%script{:src => "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"}
= Gon::Base.render_data


- vanity_url = project.vanity_url
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/p/#{vanity_url}/security.js"
    });
  })

#vulnerabilities{:style => "max-width: 405px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"}
```

The call goes then to the controller

```
class VulnerabilitiesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_project_or_fail
  before_action :set_best_project_security_set
  before_action :set_releases
  before_action :set_vulnerabilities

  def vulnerabilities_per_version
    gon.watch.release_versions = @releases.map { |r| r.version }
    puts gon.release_versions
  end

  private 

  def set_project_or_fail
    project_id = params[:project_id] || params[:id]
    @project = Project.by_vanity_url_or_id(project_id).take
    raise ParamRecordNotFound unless @project
  end

  def set_best_project_security_set
    @best_project_security_set = @project.best_project_security_set
  end

  def set_releases
    @releases = @best_project_security_set.releases.order(released_on: :asc).limit(10)
  end

  def set_vulnerabilities
    @vulnerabilities = Array.new(3) { [] }
    @releases.each do |r|
      @vulnerabilities[0] << r.vulnerabilities.low.count
      @vulnerabilities[1] << r.vulnerabilities.medium.count
      @vulnerabilities[2] << r.vulnerabilities.high.count
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, the release_versions variable is being passed to `gon` and I can view it in the logs that the values that I am looking for are there.

Once we leave the controller, the `js.erb` file is rendered:

```
vulnerabilites_per_version.js.erb

alert(gon.watch.release_versions)

$(function () {
    $('#vulnerabilities').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Vulnerabilities per Version',
            align: 'left',
            style: {
                color: '#336699',
                fontSize: 16
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align:  'left',
          itemWidth: 127
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: gon.release_versions
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Vulnerabilities'
            },

            .........code.....
```

What could be the cause of this problem? Why am I unable to access the data in my `js.erb` file? According to the `gon` documentation, I should have everything set in order for the data to render yet it doesn't. As a second attempt, I also proceeded to read up on the `gon.watch` usage but again no luck. Any ideas? Help on the matter would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Is gone available in the console? When you inspect and type `gon`, does that object exist? If it exists, is it the property you added to it that does not?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `gon` is here but if you declare `gon` as an instance variable (`@gon`), that should do the trick.

Controller

```
def show
  @dog = Dog.first
  cat = Cat.first
end
```

View: `show.html.erb`

```
@dog.name => "Sparky"
cat.name  => undefined method 'name' for nil class
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `js.erb` file isn't updating the global `gon` variable.

Try setting the global gon variable in the template:

```
#vulnerabilites_per_version.js.erb
gon = #{gon}
console.log(gon.watch.release_versions)
```